# Page blank when trying to verify password from database

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

The following is the beginning of header.php, which is a file included at the top of all my pages. As it is now, every page it's included on comes out blank in the browser -- what can I have done wrong? (The login credentials for the database, here replaced with x:es, are correct.)

```
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['log_out'])) {
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    $_SESSION = array();
}

if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

    $salt1 = "ghjfdghpuaqXC"
    $salt2 = "GHLUYKRGrtuuh"
    $password = sha1($salt1 . $_POST['password'] . $salt2);

    $db_hostname = 'xxxxxxxx';
    $db_username = 'xxxxxxxx';
    $db_password = 'xxxxxxxx';
    $db_database = 'xxxxxxxx';

$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);

if (!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db($db_database)
        or die("Unable to select database: " . mysql_error());

    $query = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE name = '" . $_POST['username'] . "'";
    $passwordindatabase = mysql_query($query);

    if ($password == $passwordindatabase) {
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
        $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['username'];
        unset($_POST['username']);
        unset($_POST['password']);
    }
}
```

Comment: parse error? otherwise, `error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` at the top of your script.

Comment: Thanks. Page was still blank even after turning error reporting on, but I'll keep it in mind for next time.

Comment: Yeah it wouldn't have mattered in this case, because there are no errors ... it's just the default response when I see white screen of death :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql_query` returns a MySQL resource. This resource must first be 'converted' to some PHP value, e.g. a string or an array.

You want to compare a resource (as returned by `mysql_query`) with a string (the password). Those, of course, will never match. So you must first convert the resource to a string. For any future queries with multiple selected columns, I'll first convert it to an array:

`$resultarray = mysql_fetch_assoc($passwordindatabase);`

Then the password can be fetched from this array:

`$resultstring = $resultarray['password'];`

As a sidenote, may I point out that you must **ABSOLUTELY** escape raw POST results like `$_POST['username']` with `mysql_real_escape_string` before feeding them to your database?

Comment: Thanks. Adding this and a couple of missing semicolons made the page show. Also thanks for the reminder about mysql_real_escape_string. I'm still not able to retrieve and compare the password from the database, but I'll create a new question for that with the updated code for the complete web page.

Answer (score 3):

i guess you should use mysql_fetch_row or mysql_fetch_assoc on your password query to use the output

```
$passwordindatabase = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query($query));
```

Answer (score 0):

The lines

```
$passwordindatabase = mysql_query($query);
```

and

```
if ($password == $passwordindatabase) {
```

dont make sense. You should use:

$passwordindatabase just contains the query, not a result !
and then, after getting the result, you should assign the exact result variable, like this:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($passwordindatabase != 0) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $passwordindatabase = $row["password"];
}
```